# Flutter / Dart : Accessing Class methods for cleaner code implementation access. Building steps on previous methods

Tags: flutter, class, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

I worked on this and its day 3 now. I'm super frustrated because I'm trying to write cleaner code.

**(Part 1): Trying to make it into a class**

// Getting instances of the method but no method output.

**(Part 2): Code works on Dartpad**

// Need this in a class and how to call on methods for use in other classes.

// **(Part 1: class FindPoundsToGallons is not working)** // tried several different ways

// I want to be able to call on and reuse the classes across the application is what I'm going for...

// I can't seem to call the correct output when I try them in a class.

```
class FindPoundsToGallons {
  late num userInputSpgr;
  late num userInputLbsIssued;
  double numCon833 = 8.33;

  FindPoundsToGallons({
    required this.userInputSpgr,
    required this.userInputLbsIssued,
    required this.numCon833,
  });
}

void poundsToGallons() {
  num spgr = 1.5; // sample number
  num lbs = 15; // sample number
  num step1Result = findWeightOfFuel(spgr1: spgr);
  num step2Result = findGallons(step1Result, lbs1: lbs);
  num step3Result = findTotalWeight(step1Result, lbs1: lbs);
  num step4Result = finalResult(step1Result,step2Result,step3Result);
// ToDo: Tell user rounded down to the nearth tenth place

  // print(finalResult);
  print(step1Result.toStringAsFixed(2));
  print(step2Result.toStringAsFixed(1));
  print(step3Result.toStringAsFixed(1));
}

num findWeightOfFuel({required num spgr1}) {
  return (spgr1 * numCon833);
}

num findGallons(num step1result, {required num lbs1}) {
  return (lbs1 / step1result);
}

num findTotalWeight(num step2Result, {required num lbs1}) {
  return (step2Result * lbs1);
}
String finalResult(num step2Result, {required num lbs1}) {
  return ('$lbs / $spgi * numCon833 = $finalResult');
}
```

// Tried examples of:

```
FindPoundsToGallons q1 = FindPoundsToGallons();
```

// to return

```
q1.findWeightOfFuel //
```

[Pounds to Gallons Multistep class methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp3fq.png)

**Part 2: // This part works on Dartpad / I need it in a class.**

```
// Formula: Pounds To Gallons
// Trying to put this into a class for later and trying to call on the methods but I keep getting instances of it without being able to see the output when I have them in a class I try to create. 


void main() {
  num spgr = 2;
  num lbs = 5;

  num step1Result = findWeightOfFuel(spgr1: spgr);

  num step2Result = findGallons(step1Result, lbs1: lbs);

  num step3Result = findTotalWeight(step1Result, lbs1: lbs);


  // print(finalResult);
  print(step1Result.toStringAsFixed(2)); // outputs: 18.66
  print(step2Result.toStringAsFixed(1)); // outputs: 0.3
  print(step3Result.toStringAsFixed(1)); // outputs: 93.3
}

num findWeightOfFuel({required num spgr1}) {
  return (spgr1 * 9.33);
}

num findGallons(num step1result, {required num lbs1}) {
  return (lbs1 / step1result);
}

num findTotalWeight(num step2Result, {required num lbs1}) {
  return (step2Result * lbs1);
}
```

// Thanks for the assistance AND as you can see I have tried, but I need some help!
**Thank you for your time and consideration!**

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what exactly the problem is your facing?

Comment: Sure thing. I went back and re-edited the post to try to make it clearer. I set the class to a new object, then I call on the method and get an instance of it without the actual output when I use it in the application. Can you help me restructure my class, and or what do I need to call on correctly with the return types to call on that method?  I'm sure it's a simple solution that I overlook every time but I'm close.

Comment: make  the poundsToGallons function not void but num and return step4Result at the end of it. So if you want to use it you would do: num solution = FindPoundsToGallons(userInputSpgr: 4, userInputLbsIssued: 5, numCon833: 3).poundsToGallons();